# Onchange from visualforce unable to get the value from Javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce

I have VF page as below

```
<apex:page standardController="Stack__c" extensions="Controller" tabStyle="Account">
<script>
function foo(data){    
    alert("Call came ");//this is displyed
    var d = document.getElementById(data).value;
alert('********The field value is ********'+d);// unable to get the value
}
 </script>
<apex:detail />

    <apex:form id="fid">
    <apex:pagemessages />
        <apex:pageBlock id="pgblock1">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"  onClick="unitval();" />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!reset}" value="Edit"/>              
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" title="Order Pad" rendered="{!rend}" id="pgsid" >                               
                <apex:inputField value="{!Stack__c.Ordered__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Stack__c.Unit_OP__c}"  onchange="foo('{!$Component.pgsid.pgblock1.fid.unit}');" id="unit"/>                    
            </apex:pageBlockSection>                             
        </apex:pageBlock>       
    </apex:form>   
</apex:page>
```

When the user change the value from the Unit_OP__c field then I am unable to get the value from the script.Please tell me how to get the value in  java script.

Please some one help me
Best Regards,
Ramesh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change following line

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Stack__c.Unit_OP__c}"  onchange="foo(this.id);" id="unit"/>
```

Even better approach will be to send current element to JavaScript function rather than passing only id & then finding same element.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Stack__c.Unit_OP__c}"  onchange="foo(this);" id="unit"/> 


function foo(data){    
    alert("Call came ");//this is displyed
alert('********The field value is ********'+data.value);
}
```